# Get Sum Of Days Between Two Days Excluding Sundays

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for storing Leave information for employees with the following fields-LeaveID, EmployeeID, NoOfDays, StartDate, EndDate, Status. I use the query below to Sum the total No days taken between two dates.

The Problem is that if there is a Sunday between the dates, its sums the day too and I don't intend it to be so. Also if let's say an employee applied for leave between 29th Jan and 2nd Feb- Which is 5 days- And I select 1st-31st Jan as my @startdate and @enddate respectively, I get zero as the Sum instead of 3days(29,30,31st).

I need your help here guys, am still new to SQL server

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(NoOfDays), 0) AS SumOfDays
FROM LeaveApplications
WHERE StartDate>=@startdate
  AND EndDate <=@enddate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stored Procedure to get the number days between two days, excluding sunday! The idea is pretty simple, you have to traverse each day, and increment count if it is not sunday:

NB: Don't Really sure is there any pre-defined function or not!

```
   Create Procedure GetDays(@Date1 Date, @Date2 Date)
   AS 
   Begin
           Declare @Length As Int = 0
           -- get total number days to iterate
           Set @Length = DateDiff(Day, @Date1, @Date2)
           Declare @i As Int = 1
           Declare @CountDays AS Int = 0

           While (@i <= @Length)
           Begin
           -- get each day name
                Declare @Name As VarChar(15) = Format(@Date1, 'dddd')
                If(@Name != 'SUNDAY') -- increment count if it is not sunday
                     Set @CountDays = @CountDays+1
           -- increment day
                Set @Date1 = DateAdd(Day, 1, @Date1)
                Set @i = @i +1
           End
         Select @CountDays 'Total Days Excluding Sunday'
    End

 -- execute procedure
 Exec dbo.GetDays '2019-02-01', '2019-02-5'
```